# Index & Match function giving duplicated value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to match the names to the numbers.

I got the `C7:C11` using the `SORT(TRANSPOSE(B3:F3,2,FALSE)`

Using `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` at `B7:B11`, I want to get the names that reflect the numbers but its showing me duplicated returns. As there is 2 of "2", the name reflected will show up as "B" twice.

The index and match function I'm using :

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$1,MATCH(C7,$B$3:$F$3,0))
```

I'm fairly new to this so I've no idea how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way in `Google Sheets`, it should work,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `D7`

```
=INDEX(FILTER($B$1:$F$1,C7=$B$3:$F$3),COUNTIF($C$7:C7,C7))
```

---

And if you are using in `Excel` then either of the ways based on `Excel Version`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `D7` --> Applicable to `Excel 2021/MS365`

```
=INDEX(FILTER($B$1:$F$1,$C7=$B$3:$F$3),COUNTIF($C$7:C7,C7))
```

• Formula used in cell `E7` --> Applicable to `All Excel Versions Except Excel 2007`

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($B$3:$F$3)-COLUMN($B$3)+1)/($C7=$B$3:$F$3),COUNTIF($C$7:C7,C7)))
```

---

As an alternative for Excel, version dependent as suggested by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir,

```
=TOCOL(SORTBY(B1:F1,B3:F3))
```

Or,

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORTBY(B1:F1,B3:F3))
```

Or, in Google sheets, with `QUERY()` Function

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B1:F3),"Select Col3, Col1 Order By Col3")
```

Comment: Just for fun, `=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B1:F3),"Select Col1 Order By Col3")` might work too for all answers in a single go.

Comment: Sir, this duplicate record return has always bothered me when using `GS` though not an issue in Excel, I always use the one I have shown thank you for sharing the alternative one.

Comment: It's a nice versatile function. In fact, `=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B1:F3),"Select Col3, Col1 Order By Col3")` would not even require knowing the ranked numbers either.

Comment: Yes sir, but its not referencing the `C7:C11` how to reference that using `QUERY()`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, I might be wrong but it seems that this is just the different numbers from `B3:F3` in ascending order. Makes me think OP does not even need to know `C7:C11` beforehand. But that's just my theory =)

Comment: Alright Sir. Sir, but you know sometimes when we extract multiple records in Excel using `FILTER()` or `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()` but what is the right way using in `Google Sheets`., Shall I follow the one you have given then.

Comment: OP is very happy with your answer, so leave it as is (or include the option as an alternative). For Excel, version dependent I'd use `=TOCOL(SORTBY(B1:F1,B3:F3))` or swap `TOCOL()` with `TRANSPOSE()`.